# Не получается вывести в нужном виде данные

Tags: pandas, numpy, sklearn

```
test_df.loc[test_df['last_price'] > 5650000, 'price_class'] = 1
test_df.loc[test_df['last_price'] <= 5650000, 'price_class'] = 0


test_features = test_df.drop(['last_price', 'price_class'], axis=1)
test_target = test_df['price_class']

test_predictions = model.predict(test_features)

print(f"Предсказание: {test_predictions}")
print(f"Правильные ответы: {test_target}")

outptut:
Предсказание: [0. 0. 1.]
Правильные ответы: 0    0.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
Name: price_class, dtype: float64
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в "Правильные ответы" был такой же вывод как "Предсказание".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_target` - это объект `pandas.Series`, который печатается в 2 колонки - индекс и значения. Для вывода как `numpy.array` необходимо преобразовать `test_target` с помощью метода  `to_numpy()` или использовать свойство `values`

```
print(f"Правильные ответы: {test_target.to_numpy()}")

# или 

print(f"Правильные ответы: {test_target.values}")
```

```
Правильные ответы: [0. 1. 0.]
```